# Query with Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Model Employee with holidays attribute.
I want create a query that return the employee not in holidays.

For Example:

```
employees = Employee.where("disease = ? AND (Date.today < holidays.starts_at OR Date.today > holidays.ends_at)", false).order("engagement ASC").all
```

Employees Model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :holidays, :dependent => :destroy

  after_initialize do
    self.acceso ||= true
  end
end
```

Holidays Model have `:starts_at, :ends_at, :employee_id` attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do something like

```
current_holidays = Holiday.where(["starts_at <= :now AND ends_at >= :now", {:now => Time.now}])
employees_on_holiday = current_holidays.map(&:employee_id)
employees_not_on_holiday = Employee.where(["NOT id IN (?)", employees_on_holiday])
```

Adjust to your needs, and I'm sure it should be possible to do in a single query as well.